# pysnmp: how to dynamically check username and passphrase in snmp server

Tags: python, authentication, snmp, pysnmp

i have a sql based database that contain some username and hashed passwords.
also i am trying to develop a snmp server via pysnmp to report some information about application.

what i need is a method that check snmp username and hash of passphrase dynamically corresponding to user and hashed password stored in database when a request received by my snmp server and authenticate this user and response to it.

for example if i have this user in date base

```
username |   hashed password 
-------------------------------
admin    | <hash for 12345678>
```

when this snmp request receive

```
snmpwalk -v3 -l authNoPriv -u admin -A 12345678  127.0.0.1:1616 .1.3.6.1
```

then my snmp server hash `12345678` and check database for user `admin` and hash of `12345678` and if correct response and if not correct message about failed authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

I found user information store in a table in snmp agent. so perhaps if i create this table dynamically i will achieve my goal.